# How can I show that for all $v\in V$ there's $F\in V^{**} $ such that $F(f)=f(v)$ for all $f\in V^*$?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, dual-spaces

I'm trying to show that the map $\Phi :V\to V^{**}$ given by $\Phi (v)(f):=f(v)$ is well-defined. To show that I need to prove that for all $v\in V$ there's $F\in V^{**}
$ such that $F(f)=f(v)$ for all $f\in V^*$. However I don't know how to prove that in the **infinite** dimensional case!

**My question:** Suppose that $V$ is an infinite dimensional vector space. How can I show that for all $v\in V$ there's $F\in V^{**}
$ such that $F(f)=f(v)$ for all $f\in V^*$?

Below there's a lemma that I'm trying to use to prove the question above.

**Lemma:** Let $V$ be a vector space. Suppose that $\{v_i\}_{i\in I}$ is a base of $V$. Then there's a unique linearly independent subset $\{v^i\}_{i\in I}$ of $V^*$ such that $v^i(v_j)=\delta _{ij}$ for all $i,j\in I$ in which $\delta $ is the Kronecker delta.

---

**EDIT:**

I'll clarify my question:

Given two sets $A$ and $B$, we say that $f\subseteq A\times B$ is a map from $A$ to $B$ (which we denote by $f:A\to B$) if $(\forall x\in A)(\exists !y\in B)\left((x,y)\in f\right)$ is a true proposition.

So, my question is to prove that $\Phi :=\big\{(v,F)\in V\times V^{**}:(\forall  f\in V^*)\left(F(f)=f(v)\right)\big\}$ is a map from $V$ to $V^{**}$. That is, I want to prove that $(\forall v\in V)(\exists! F\in V^{**})\left((v,F)\in \Phi \right)$ is a true proposition.

Comment: Simply verify that if you define a map $F: V^*\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ in this way, it is bounded and linear.

Comment: The proof is just as straightforward in the infinite dimensional case.

Comment: As Jonathan says, what you have is a _definition_ of $F$ (I would consider indexing it as $F_v$ to make it clear that there's one for each $v\in V$); you just have to show that that definition meets the conditions for $F_v$ to be an element of $V^{**}$.

Comment: @JonathanHole In my question $V^{**}$ is the algebraic double dual of $V$. That is, the elements of $V^*$ are just linear functionals (not necessarily continuous)!

Comment: @StevenStadnicki My problem is finding a linear map $F\in V^{**}$ such that $F(f)=f(v)$ **for all**  $v\in V$ and **for all** $f\in V^*$. I don't how to solve the problem using your suggestion!

Comment: Then it becomes even easier -- you don't have to show it is bounded!

Comment: @rfloc I think you have your quantifiers wrong. There isn't a _single_ linear map that works for every $v$; rather, for _each_ $v$ there's a $F_v$ that is a map from $V^*\mapsto \mathbb{R}$ (or whatever your underlying field/ring/what-have-you is). And _defining_ $F_v$ by saying $F_v(f)=f(v)$ is a map from $V^*\mapsto\mathbb{R}$; you just need to show linearity.

Comment: The map $\Phi$ that you're trying to show exists is then the map that takes each $v$ to its corresponding $F_v$.

Comment: Please see my edit in my question because I believe nobody understood my question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that $V$ is a vector space over a field $k$. Take $v \in V$. Then, if you define a map $\Phi(v) : V^* \to k$ by $$(\forall f \in V^*) \quad \Phi(v)(f) = f(v)$$ note that $\Phi(v)$ is well-defined ($f \in V^* \implies \Phi(v)(f) \in k$) and is linear since if $f_1,f_2 \in V^*$ and $\lambda \in k$, $$\Phi(v)(\lambda f_1+f_2) = (\lambda f_1+f_2)(v) = \lambda f_1(v)+f_2(v) = \lambda \Phi(v)(f_1)+\Phi(v)(f_2).$$ Thus, $\Phi(v) \in (V^*)^* =: V^{**}$, and then $\Phi : V \to V^{**}$ is well-defined!

Comment: Please see my edit in my question because you didn't understand my question!

Comment: I showed that for any $v \in V$ there is a unique $F \in V^{**}$ (namely, $F = \Phi(v)$) such that $F(f) = f(v)$ for all $f \in V^*$. Uniqueness of $\Phi(v)$ follows from the fact that if $F$ is some other element of $V^{**}$ such that $F(f) = f(v)$ for all $f \in V^*$, then $F$ and $\Phi(v)$ are two functions from $V^*$ to $k$ that coincide in every $f \in V^*$, so $F = \Phi(v)$. Also, I didn't showed that $\Phi$ is linear, I showed that $\Phi(v)$ is an element of $V^{**}$ for any $v \in V$, which is different.

Comment: Let $V,W$ be two vector spaces. I know that if $\{v_i\}_{i \in I}$ is a base of $V$ and $\{w_i\}_{ i\in I}$ is a collection of elements of $W$, then there's a unique linear map $T:V\to W$ such that $T(v_i)=w_i$ for all $i\in I$. However I don't know to use this fact to prove that existence of a linear map $F:V^*\to k$ such that **for all** $f\in V^*$ we have $F(f)=f(v)$.

Comment: @rfloc Is there a reason that you believe that we should use this fact to prove the existence of such a map?

Comment: @BenGrossmann This fact show that (generally) we can't define a linear map with specific values for all elements of its domain!

Comment: @rfloc That's right. But, isn't $\Phi(v) : V^* \to k$ a linear map such that $\Phi(v)(f) = f(v)$ **for all** $f \in V^*$?

Comment: @rfloc *Generally* here is key. However, **if** one defines a map for all values within the domain **and then** shows that this definition is consistent with the definition of linearity, then one has indeed shown that there exists a linear map that is described by the definition.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Now I understood! Thank you for your clarification!